# lightning:input behaves strangely with Non-US(german/french) locale

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, platform-bug, lightninginput, localization

In my app there are many users with a **German or French locale**. Both have in common that they use **comma as decimal separator** (opposed to Apex, JS and US-citizens which use a dot .) The dot instead is used as thousand separator.

When they need to enter a decimal number into `lightning:input`

```
<lightning:input aura:id="input" value="{!v.value}" type="number" variant="label-hidden" label="Value"
                     disabled="{# v.readonly}"
                     step="{# v.type == 'currency' ? 'any'
                             : v.type == 'percent' ? '0.01' : '1'}"
                     min="{# v.type == 'currency' ? '' : '0'}"
                     max="{# v.type == 'percent' ? '100' : ''}"
                     formatter="{# v.type == 'percent' ? 'percent-fixed' : ''}" />
```

they experience different symptoms:

**SYMPTOM 1**: They cannot enter a comma at all

**SYMPTOM 2**: When they use a dot instead it gets displayed correctly as a comma

**SYMPTOM 3**: When they save this number to the database the dot basically gets ignored as German thousand seperator at the wrong position

Please see this **video** showing all the symptoms:
https://youtu.be/rE_r1-kA6fY

> Note: Maybe it is because this component is still in **BETA**, but as
>   this is not documented I have to assume it will not be fixed soon.

Comment: can you share a code of a single cell

Comment: What code are you interested in. Lightning controller or markup and which parts are of interest?

Comment: it seems like the problem is in the markup - so show us markup code of a single cell

Comment: Is that enough?

Comment: Hello. Have you tried using `lightning:formattedNumber`? You may try assigning dynamic currencyCode values according to the user's locale. 

`<lightning:formattedNumber value="5000" style="currency" currencyCode="USD" />` .

Comment: A lightning:formattedNumber component displays formatted numbers for decimals, currency, and percentages. This component uses the Intl.NumberFormat JavaScript object to format numerical values. The locale set in the app's user preferences determines how numbers are formatted. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedNumber.htm

Comment: Did you see any solution towards this? Same issue with different locales which need to be supported. From English (US) to Dutch to ... ui:inputNumber field behaves correctly but does not have Lightning Design applied.